# How to show the current file being edited in the project view in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.1.  Suppose I have a file open in the editor, and I want to see it in the project view (usually so I can open a sibling file).  How do I do that?

I've googled all manner of "navigate" and "find" and such, and it's always some related concept, but not this one.

Comment: I want this too. We should ask jetbrains for the feature.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Navigate | Select In... (Alt-F1 in the default keymap), then select "Project View".

Comment: `Alt-F1` worked perfectly.  I also wanted to add that the current version of the UI shows a set of crosshairs (⌖) in the Project pane's top-right corner which performs the same function for the shortcut-impaired.  Not sure what version introduced this.

Answer (score 96):

I got here, so maybe this will help some other folks like me :

How to show current working file in pycharm Project:

1. `Alt + 1 \ Ctrl + Shift + 1` - open the Project nav bar.
2. Click the little `settings wheel` in top right of the project bar
   [image: settings wheel]
3. Mark the `"Always Select Opened File"`.

[image]

Now try and navigate to some files and watch them being displayed in the project bar .

Comment: Is there a hotkey to perform the function of "auto scroll from source"? I don't see anything like it in the keymap, though.

Comment: I guess there's "select in" > 1 (defaults to alt + F1, but I had to remap because that hotkey didn't work for me at all). It's two keystrokes instead of 1. Although also more versatile, I guess. That's from the accepted answer, but I'd rather something that is one key stroke.

Comment: For me I am not able to see this option, mine is Pycharm community 2019

Answer (score 19):

1. `CMD-SHIFT-A` (on Mac) to open the action selector
2. Type `sip` which should highlight "Select in Project View"
3. `ENTER`

Answer (score 10):

In current/later versions of PyCharm 2020.1 you

- Open Project tab `(Alt + 1)`
- Click Settings (little gear) icon on top right corner of the Project tab
- Check option `Always Select Opened File`

Answer (score 10):

*For PyCharm 2020.1*

**Step 1:** Open project tab from View menu or use keyboard shortcut `(Alt + 1)`

[image]

**Step 2:** From the project tab click the gear icon and check option `Always Select Opened File`

[image]

Comment: Works for PyCharm 2021.1 too

Answer (score 7):

The quickest way to do this is to click the 'Scroll From Source' Button, which looks a little like a crosshair from FPS games.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yole's answer is what you asked for but in regards to opening sibling files, you can do that in less keystrokes.

There is a keymap for `Jump to Navigation Bar` (`cmd + up` for me) this puts you to where the file currently is then you can use `up` and `down` to navigate adjacent files.

Comment: Useful, but not the answer. Upvotted anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to
Settings -> Keymap -> Other -> Select In Project View
and add a keyboard shortcut to this one because it's empty by default

Comment: I'm used to the equivalent functionality in Atom, so this is the right answer for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

It is very convenient, in my opinion, to use a sequence of the following keys:

1. Alt-F1
2. Just number button 1

This way you can show a file without having to use a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

With the "IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)"

I found this, by searching for three dot, at top of Project sidebar (left side, just beside the string Project)

Clicking on 3 dots, directly gave the option "Always Select Opened File".